# Synthesizing a pure tone in Frequency Domain: can it be done more efficiently?

Tags: dft, sinc

I came to the conclusion that synthesizing pure tones in Frequency Domain is *much* less efficient than synthesizing cosines in Time Domain and then computing the FFT. But I suspect this is the case here only because I am ignoring a better formula.

Namely:

Synthesizing a cosinusoid of given frequency, phase and magnitude in time domain just requires a complex number initialized with given phase and magnitude, rotating it at every sample by a simple complex multiplication, and taking its Real part as current sample.

Synthesizing a pure tone of given frequency, phase and magnitude in Frequency Domain requires instead computing a complex Aliased Sinc function, which even if highly optimized, still requires a lot more operations including one unavoidable division:

```
(sin(PI(x-f))/sin(PI(x-f)/z)) * exp(i * (1+1/z)*PI*(x-f)+2PI*f+p)
```

(everything then scaled to m/z) where f is the frequency in bin units (cycles per frame), p is the initial phase in radians, z is the dft frame size in samples and m the magnitude. Note that this seems the only valid formula to compute a perfect spectral peak, corresponding to a time domain signal without distortions, for every x from zero (DC bin) to z/2 (Nyquist bin) continuing up to z-1 in the negative frequencies end.

I am perfectly aware that, by using a Hann window function, you can restrict rendering to few bins and the resulting error will be masked by using an overlapping stft scheme, but that is NOT my question, since I am rather interested in synthesizing a *perfect* spectral peak body, and not an approximation (like using a non aliased sinc function in place of the aliased i.e periodic one as I heard somebody does, and which leads to a distorced signal).

So my question to math gurus is:
is there any way to compute the complex aliased sinc function as efficiently as it is computing a plain cosinusoid, i.e a simple formula to compute every bin iteratively, as I can compute samples iteratively in the time domain case ?
Unfortunately the maths skills needed to prove or disprove my question are beyond my knowledge!

Thanks

Comment: Good question! I suspect the answer is "no", but I don't have any deeper reasoning other than what you've put in your question.

Comment: I think your time domain generation is also overly complex. You only need initial phase and either phase increment for each sample, or time multiplied with frequency.

Comment: @PeterK I am currently investigating with the Discrete Summation formula, after all a peak body in frequency domain is also a bandlimited (complex) Dirac pulse, which can be expressed as a sum of discrete complex sinusoids. I have just to see if such formula can be adapted to have every discrete sinusoid phase shifted by a linear amount (to give the Dirac pulse the right frequency offset) or not, AND if the resulting operations needed are still more than those required by the time-domain case...

Comment: @Justme why do you say it is overly complex ? AFAIK the easiest way to compute a (co)sinusoid, i.e without using trig functions or tables, is initializing a complex number P with the desired initial phase and radius; then compute a complex coefficient K with unitary radius and suitable argument in function of the desired frequency; for every sample you just do P = P * K, so that Re(P) and Im(P) are the wanted cosinusoid and sinusoid. It just takes one complex multiplication i.e two algebric sums and four multiplications. If you are really aware of a more efficient way you are welcome :)

Comment: It depends on implementation of the device you run the code, obviously, but as your method is iterative, you may run into precision issues, and obviously the K must be initialized with sin/cos of phase increment, P must be initialized with sin/cos of initial phase. And radius of P and K must be exactly 1 or the result approaches zero or infinity. Is one cos() that much inefficient than iterative complex multiplication? Genrally one option is to have a sin lookup/waveform table and use DDS method.

Comment: In am coding in cpp. No matter what, a sin/cos operation for every sample is much more cpu consuming than my rotating phasor method. And using a lookup table seems efficient at first glance but is not so much, because it involves one further memory access and some interpolation code which, despite written efficiently, must always rely on an (int) cast which has its weight. So after benchmarking, my method always turned out the fastest. I am aware of the risk of cumulative precision loss, but in case of short renders the error is negligible and the radius always stable

Comment: As an update to my comment to PeterK, sadly I was so stupid not to realize suddently that the discrete summation formula I mentioned leads directly to the formula I wrote in my question. No way: computing a sinc always requires a division by two real sines. I can just optimize the formula the most extent possible but it will always require much more operations than those required in T.D